# how to get private key from passpharase in php?

Tags: private-key, php, passphrase, recover-private-key

i have a passpharase bitcoin, but i don't know how to get private key from my passpharase. I tried using blockchain and electrum and it worked. but here what I need is to find the private key using php.

please help me how to find the private key?

Comment: Do you mean you have a *mnemonic seed phrase* (generally 12 or 24 words long)? This is different than a password/passphrase.

Answer (score -2):

if you have mnemonic seed phrase
use offline
https://iancoleman.io/bip39/

Comment: The question asks how to do this in PHP though.